# "Merging two files" using operator "+"

Tags: c++, file, operator-overloading, concatenation

I was wondering, if it would be possible to code something like this:

```
File1("dataOut.txt")=File2("Data1.txt")+File3("Data2.txt")
```

I believe the thing I seek is to achieve concatenation via `operator+`.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but I would have to overload that operator somewhere?

I know it would probably be easier to just copy contents from both files straight into output file, but I would like to do it with `operator+`.

Comment: `File1`, `File2`, `File3` being what kind of variables?

Comment: .. of course, `File1`, `File2` and `File3` are of some class type you wrote yourself. Right?

Comment: Absolutely possible, but you should absolutely NOT do this.

Comment: No , with File1 etc i mean regular (lets say) .txt files with random content (numbers, strings..)

Comment: How do you represent those .txt files in your program?

Comment: Hmm , not sure what you mean. In the program i work with certain string and variables and then i put them into a certain file. Lets say File 1 contains Names, and File 2 contains Phone numbers. I would like to create a new File where contents from both Phone numbers and Names files would be inserted - and all that using "+" (if possible).

Comment: Umm ... so why not write those same names and phone numbers into the third file?

Comment: How would you merge, by line?  by paragraph?  by word?  by sentence? Or would the operation consist of appending `File3` to the end of `File2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not provide some magical handling for your abstract logic, it cannot just work out that `File1=File2+File3` means you want to merge two files together.

Firstly, those variables would have to be some form of 'type', and to have the logic you want, a type of your own devising. It would be constructed from a `std::string` which would be the file name. You would then need to define an `operator+`, this operator would have to some how combine the file names to produce a new one, then make a new file in the operating system, and then add the content of the other two files, finally return a new instance of this type which has this new file name.

As I said in a comment though, you really shouldn't do this. Generally speaking, you should not overload operators in C++, unless doing so has VERY clear and obvious results. For instance, a (maths) vector class, fairly clear what `vector_a + vector_b` would (should) do. However, these 'files', it's not so clear, just look at the questions people had to ask. Just one of those should raise a big red flag that it is not a good idea.

You should just use a 'normal' function to do what you want to do, something with a name that makes it clear what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot add two files together like that

Instead you have to use `ifstream` and `ofstream` from the `fstream` library

Here is an example that you can use

```
std::ifstream file1( "Data1.txt" ) ;
std::ifstream file2( "Data2.txt" ) ;
std::ofstream combined_file( "dataOut.txt" ) ;
combined_file << file1.rdbuf() << file2.rdbuf() ;
```

Comment: Yeah... this shows a basic example of how to copy the contents of two text files into a third... doesn't really address the question though.